# Why does order of scaling and translation matter for the model matrix?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I was playing around with creating a model matrix, and realized that the order of the operations for scale and translate matters. I'm using Qt for my matrices and use QMatrix4x4 and using openGL (but this should be library and platform agnostic, and related to the mathematics). The result of scaling down a model and then translating it only works as expected, like so.

```
    QMatrix4x4 model;
    model.translate(some_vec3d);
    model.scale(some_vec3d);
```

I was under the impression that mathematically, since the scale appears in the first 3x3 of the matrix and translation only affects the last column of the matrix (4th column) the order is independent. When I look at the matrices I understand that the order matters, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

- A vertex point in your model `p`
- A scale matrix `S`
- A translation matrix `T` by a displacement vector `t`

The transformed point obtained from applying the:

```
Translation first: 
     S * T * p = S * (p + t) 
               = S * p + S * t
                         ----- <---
Scaling first:
     T * S * p = S * p + t
                         -     <---
```

The difference illustrated in the matrix multiplication:

```
Translation first:

   | Sx 0  0  0 |   | 1 0 0 Tx |     | Sx 0  0  Sx * Tx |
   | 0  Sy 0  0 | * | 0 1 0 Ty |  =  | 0  Sy 0  Sy * Ty |
   | 0  0  Sz 0 |   | 0 0 1 Tz |     | 0  0  Sz Sz * Tz |
   | 0  0  0  1 |   | 0 0 0 1  |     | 0  0  0     1    |

Scaling first:

   | 1 0 0 Tx |   | Sx 0  0  0 |     | Sx 0  0  Tx |
   | 0 1 0 Ty | * | 0  Sy 0  0 |  =  | 0  Sy 0  Ty |
   | 0 0 1 Tz |   | 0  0  Sz 0 |     | 0  0  Sz Tz |
   | 0 0 0 1  |   | 0  0  0  1 |     | 0  0  0  1  |
```

Comment: This is a great illustration. Thanks! And the code I show works because it applies it in column-major, so the operations are reversed, as opposed to row-major as you have shown? That is scaling, followed by translation is the way it should work.

Comment: @dev_nut oh ok, I don't know what matrix convention Qt uses but OpenGL uses row-major (with Y and Z swapped). It depends on how Qt implements the translate and scale functions; some libraries apply the transformations in reverse.

Comment: Even glm you have to do the operations in reverse. I believe openGL is column-major - https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm. But, the mathematics are all the same. You just have to be aware of the order the underlying library you use expects it to be, ie qt or glm or anything else.

Comment: @dev_nut oops pardon the error; bottom line is, the matrix equations are convention-invariant, and they show that if you apply the scaling second, the translation itself will also be scaled, whereas the reverse does not apply.